# Obtain blur with soft edges

Tags: html, css, sass, frontend

I applied this code to make the content underneath a div blurry, but the edge is very sharp.

```
z-index: 10;
backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
background: rgb(255,255,255);
background: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(255,255,255,0) 10%, rgba(174,174,174,0) 15%, var(--bg-color) 85%);
```

Can I create something like a blur gradient to soften the edge and make the blur gradually disappear?

[image]

Comment: What if you try adding a css blur filter to the overlaying div. Essentially the reason the edge is sharp is b/c the div on top has a straight bottom edge. The answer below is attempting to make that bottoms edge fuzzy, I’m curious if applying the blue filter to the div will provide this same result.

Answer (score 0):

To make Tilt-Shift effect for backdrop-filter in CSS, You have to use the `mask-image` attribute like the code below:

CSS:

```
  -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
          backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
  -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, black 20%, black 100%);
          mask-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, black 20%, black 100%);
```

You can change the position of tilting by percent, but I think this config is exactly what you need.

```css
.menu{
    color: white;
    position: sticky;
    display: flex;
    place-content: space-evenly;
    align-items: center;
    height: 80px;
}

.menu:before {
    content: '';
    height: 80px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: -1;
    -webkit-backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    backdrop-filter: blur(15px);
    -webkit-mask-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, black 40%, black 100%);
    mask-image: linear-gradient(0deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, black 40%, black 100%);
}

body{
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1444080748397-f442aa95c3e5?ixlib=rb-4.0.3&ixid=MnwxMjA3fDB8MHxleHBsb3JlLWZlZWR8M3x8fGVufDB8fHx8&w=1000&q=80");
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  margin: 0;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="menu">
    <span>Home</span>
    <span>About</span>
    <span>Contact</span>
  </div>
</body>
```